# Protect all endpoints automatically

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-oidc

I am following Quarkus OpenID Connect tutorial [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect).

But I don't need to check roles.

I want all endpoints except health-check and swagger-ui to check if the token is valid. Some times I may inject the JsonWebToken to use a claim. How can I do that using the extension?

Answer (score 0):

Currently I haven't found a straight forward way to achieve this but Quarkus provides the `io.quarkus.security.Authenticated` annotation that will permit any authenticated user to access the resource (equivalent to `@RolesAllowed("**")`).

Check this guide for more information: https://quarkus.io/guides/security-authorization